# multiple RotationAnimations (time shifted) using false angles

Tags: android-animation, rotateanimation

i am trying a quite simple animation. rotate a view to the left for 18°, then rotate it to the right for 180°(relative) (+162°absolute) and then back to normal 0°(absolute) (-162°relative)...

```
int first = -18;
int second = first +180;
int animationGap = 500;
//left rotation
final RotateAnimation leftRotation = new RotateAnimation(0, first, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
leftRotation.setDuration(1000);
leftRotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
//right rotation
final RotateAnimation rightRotation = new RotateAnimation(first, second, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rightRotation.setDuration(1000);
rightRotation.setStartOffset(1000+animationGap);
rightRotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
//back to normal rotation
final RotateAnimation toNormalRotation = new RotateAnimation(second, 0, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
toNormalRotation.setDuration(1000);
toNormalRotation.setStartOffset(2000+animationGap*2);
toNormalRotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
//animation set
final AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animationSet.addAnimation(leftRotation);
animationSet.addAnimation(rightRotation);
animationSet.addAnimation(toNormalRotation);
```

and i start the whole bundle with this:

```
view.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

it is working as expected with `first= -90;` but is totally wrong with the upper constellation... (tested on samsung s4 and google nexus s)
of course i can quick fix this with `AnimationListener` and starting the next animation from it but this is no real solution or answer. 
so is there anyone who can tell my why this is happening and how i can prevent this?
**edit:**
i think the problem could be the underlaying mathematical representation as a martix (rotations may manipulate each otehr). but it should not be a problem because android could recognize this or may generate different ones because of the time delay between.
i'm still looking for a nice solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess was right and so the only solution is using `AnimationListener` for each single rotation and starting the next in the onEnd method..